# Simple query about plotting the hyperbolic paraboloid in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the following:

z=-4x+(x^2)-4y-(y^2) over [x,y]=(0:5,0:5)

Thats how I am trying to do it:

> [x,y]=meshgrid(0:5,0:5);
>
> z=-4x+(x^2)-4y-(y^2);

When I am trying to define z I get an "unexpected expression" error. Help please.

Comment: gotta add the multiplier sign to your expressions: 4*x, not 4x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your second line to `z=-4*x+(x.^2)-4*y-(y.^2);` and it should work.  You need to add a period before the carat to raise each individual element to the second power.  Otherwise MATLAB will perform a matrix multiplication.

Comment: works perfectly thanks. I am starting to use these math programms(Mathematica, Matlab, Mapple). Graphing stuff in mathematica and mapple appears to be easier than in matlab. Whats your opinion on that?

Comment: I personally have much more experience with Matlab than the other two, so that is the tool I typically use.  If you're just getting started and are mostly interested in graphing functions, I think Mathematica is probably the best in that area of the three.